# Remove Google Search suggestions

Tags: google-search, localization, personalization

Every time I type a word and then meaning (i.e. backpack meaning in...) Google suggests in Hindu, in Urdu etc.
I have no interest in these languages and never googled for them.

I would like to see suggestions for English, Spanish, Italian as these are the languages that I normally use. Almost every day I look for the meaning for an English word, but it doesn't appear as the first suggestion, instead, it appears Hindu. I understand that probably there are a lot of Indians searching for that and Google's algorithm is using it for its suggestions, but Google should prioritise my individual preferences/history and show me English/Spanish/Italian. Any way I can bring those languages at the top?

[image]

Comment: btw, those are not "suggestions" but "omnibox prediction" the "suggestion" is only the second one which offers opening google translate in urdu - for that you just need to press ARROW DOWN to highlight it and simply press SHIFT+DELETE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- go to **`chrome://settings/searchEngines`**
- set this as deafult: 

  ```
  https://encrypted.google.com/search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&safe=off&pws=0&hl=EN&q=%s
  ```

[image: 0]

Comment: your suggestion in comments doesn't work, but this one does. I just have to use it now and google seems to remember my searches. thanks.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete.